# My rails nested model isn't recognizing _destroy attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, strong-parameters

I have a parent model (cocktail) and a child (dose).

I have a nested form in which I want to be able to create/delete doses objects on the go.

The creation part works without the `_destroy` attribute in the strong params, but when I add `_destroy` to the attribute hash in order to be able to delete, I get the error `unknown attribute '_destroy' for Dose`. I'm not sure where I am wrong.

Also I have the idea that I'm over complicating my code and there should be an easier way to create the doses than the one I'm doing (is add_doses method even necessary?). If I can get some feedback on that I would really appreciate it.

Cocktail:

```
class Cocktail < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, uniqueness: true, presence: true

  has_many :doses, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :ingredients, through: :doses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :doses, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Dose:

```
class Dose < ApplicationRecord
  validates :description, presence: true
  belongs_to :cocktail
  belongs_to :ingredient
  validates :cocktail, uniqueness: { scope: :ingredient }
 end
```

Controller:

```
class CocktailsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_task, only: %i[show edit update]

  def index
    @cocktails = Cocktail.all
  end

  def show; end

  def new
    @cocktail = Cocktail.new
    @cocktail.doses.build
  end

  def create
    @cocktail = Cocktail.new(cocktail_params)
    @cocktail.save
    add_doses
    redirect_to cocktails_path
  end

  def edit; end

  def update
    @cocktail.update(cocktail_params)
    add_doses
    redirect_to cocktail_path(@cocktail)
  end

  private

  def set_task
    @cocktail = Cocktail.find(params[:id])
  end

  def cocktail_params
    params[:cocktail][:name] = params[:cocktail][:name].downcase.titleize
    params.require(:cocktail).permit(:name)
  end

  def add_doses
    @cocktail.doses.destroy_all
    strong_params = params.require(:cocktail).permit(doses_attributes: [:description, :ingredient_id, :_destroy, :id])
    params[:cocktail][:doses_attributes].each_key do |key|
      @cocktail.doses.create(strong_params[:doses_attributes][key])
    end
  end
end
```

My main form view:

```
<%= simple_form_for @cocktail do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, required: true %>
  <%= f.nested_fields_for :doses do |dose| %>
    <%= render '/cocktails/partials/doses_fields', f: dose %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
    <%= link_to_add_association 'add dose', f, :doses, partial: '/cocktails/partials/doses_fields', class: "btn btn-secondary" %>
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-secondary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My partial view to add new doses:

```
<div class='nested-fields'>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
    <%= f.association :ingredient, collection: Ingredient.all %>
    <%= link_to_remove_association "remove dose", f %>
</div>
```

If you also want to point out everything that's wrong with my code, don't hold back and be your worst ;)

Comment: The `_destroy` parameter is a special flag which is passed into the nested object attributes params so the associated object will be destroy. It is NOT an attribute of Dose therefore it breaks when you try create a new Dose with `@cocktail.doses.create(strong_params[:doses_attributes][key])`

Comment: Also I dont think you need the `_delete` since you already deleted all the associated Dose before hand with `@cocktail.doses.destroy_all`?

Comment: I added the `@cocktail.doses.destroy_all` in an attempt to make it work. And it still not deleting them that's odd. It only keeps adding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First fix your `#create` and `#update` methods so that they check if the record is actually persisted before you redirect!

Then add the nested parameters to the whitelist and axe that `add_doses` method which is a creative but extremely flawed attempt at duplicating the functionality provided by the nested attributes.

```
class CocktailsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cocktail, only: %i[show edit update]

  def index
    @cocktails = Cocktail.all
  end

  def show; end

  def new
    @cocktail = Cocktail.new
    @cocktail.doses.build
  end

  def create
    @cocktail = Cocktail.new(cocktail_params)
    if @cocktail.save
      redirect_to cocktails_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit; end

  def update
    if @cocktail.update(cocktail_params)
      redirect_to @cocktail
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def set_cocktail
    @cocktail = Cocktail.find(params[:id])
  end

  def cocktail_params
    # this should be done in the model
    params[:cocktail][:name] = params[:cocktail][:name].downcase.titleize
    params.require(:cocktail)
          .permit(
             :name,
             doses_attributes: [
               :id,
               :_destroy,
               :description,
               :ingredient_id
             ]
          )
  end
end
```

If you want to let users delete the nested records just create a checkbox:

```
<div class='nested-fields'>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
    <%= f.association :ingredient, collection: Ingredient.all %>
    <%= f.input :_destroy, as: :boolean, label: 'Remove' %>
</div>
```

You also need to fix your validation:

```
class Dose < ApplicationRecord
  validates :description, presence: true
  belongs_to :cocktail
  belongs_to :ingredient
  validates :cocktail_id, uniqueness: { scope: :ingredient_id }
end
```

When creating a uniqueness validation you need to set it up to validate the uniqueness of the actual columns and not the associations.

Comment: Awesome stuff, thanks! Just one thing that I just don't have clear, by sending just the `cocktail_params` to a cocktail object, will this be creating all the (several) nested doses inside the params by default? Is there no need for me to create some kind of loop to create one by one?

Comment: Nope. That's what nested parameters does for you. I would recommend reading the docs https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html